# How to determine where an intellisense-like suggestion comes from? (and suppress it)

Tags: ruby, intellisense, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When writing Ruby code, the following suggestion comes up each time the cursor hits an `end` statement (intellisense-like):

[image: the dreaded END/end suggestion]

It is very annoying (breaks the flow, since it must be escaped) and useless. I don't know where or what extension it comes from.

How do I determine what piece of plugin injects this suggestion?

And then, how do I shut it off?

Comment: To shut it off, setting the config `"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,` works. It has obviously larger scope than what I'd like, but it's a no-so-bad workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.json file - you have the ability to control which plugin is making recommendations - mine has the following:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": null // use rubocop for formatting
"ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
```

Purely disabling the intellisense functionality would be controlled by these settings.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

I don't believe that you can purely turn off the 'end' only intellisense - it appears to be an all-or-none proposition.